# Scraping a url value using contains and Cheeriogs

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

I use the Cheeriogs library for scraping:

https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

This is the element I need to collect the value `href`:

```
<a class="tnmscn" itemprop="url" href="/en/predictions-tips-wealdstone-solihull-moors-1455115">
```

This is the code I'm currently using to extract the value.:

```
const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);

const scrapurl = $('div.schema > div > div.tnms > div > a.tnmscn');
const urlmatch = $(scrapurl).attr('href').trim();
Logger.log(urlmatch);
```

But it's not reliable for my fear of ending up changing positions on the site and collecting other links other than the one that appears in the clickable element in that position:

[image]

So I'd like to make it more secure, so I tried using:

```
div.schema > div > div.tnms > div > a:contains("/en/predictions-tips")
```

That didn't work. How should I use `contains` for this need?

Add infos:

**Page Link**
https://www.forebet.com/en/teams/wealdstone

**Image to element**

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your question? How is it your current css unreliable? Could you tell us what output you're expecting? I see there are two nodes that match your rules, do you want both of the values? `'/en/predictions-tips-wealdstone-solihull-moors-1455115', 
'/en/predictions-tips-northampton-walsall-fc-1474257'`? Have you tried simply `a.tnmscn::attr(href)`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the indication of doubt, I added more details of the position where the desired value is. @Granitosaurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following selectors?

#### From:

```
const scrapurl = $('div.schema > div > div.tnms > div > a.tnmscn');
```

#### To:

```
const scrapurl = $('a.tnmscn[href^="/en/predictions"]');
```

or

```
const scrapurl = $('div.schema > div > div.tnms > div > a.tnmscn[href^="/en/predictions"]');
```

or

```
const scrapurl = $('div.schema > div > div.tnms > div > a[href^="/en/predictions"]');
```

- In the above all-modified scripts, `/en/predictions-tips-wealdstone-solihull-moors-1455115` is retrieved.
- In above selectors, the start text of `href` in the tag `a` and the tag `a` with the class `tnmscn` is `/en/predictions`.

But, from the URL you are using, 2 values are retrieved. This has already been mentioned by [Granitosaurus's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445174/scraping-a-url-value-using-contains-and-cheeriogs#comment122745371_69445174). So I think that when you want to retrieve the 1st value, the above modification for your script can be used.

If you want to retrieve 2 values, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the above modified selectors can be also used.

```js
const url = "https://www.forebet.com/en/teams/wealdstone";
const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
const scrapurl = $('div.schema > div > div.tnms > div > a.tnmscn[href^="/en/predictions"]'); // and a.tnmscn[href^="/en/predictions"]
$(scrapurl).each(function() {
  const urlmatch = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(urlmatch);
});
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    /en/predictions-tips-wealdstone-solihull-moors-1455115
    /en/predictions-tips-crawley-town-leyton-orient-1474259
  ```

#### References:

- [Selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
- [cheeriogs](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs)

Comment: Hello friend @Tanaike , your answer solved my problem, however you felt doubts regarding the question of recovered values, I added to the question an addition about my question of lack of confidence in collecting the correct href.

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.